# How to make UITabBarItem a button without it changing the view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a UITabBarItem (Contact) set up through storyboard which when I click it goes to a blank view. Programatically I have also set this tab up to open up a Mail Composer view, and when the Mail Composer View is closed I set the active index to a different tab.

Now the problem is, when I click the tab for Contact, for a brief, but noticeable period you can see the blank view. What I would like is for the button to not lead anywhere at all, but to still be able to click it to open up a Mail Composer View.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your UITabBarControllerDelegate, implement [–tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarControllerDelegate/tabBarController%3ashouldSelectViewController%3a), making it return NO if the user selects the "Contact" UITabBarButton.

```
- (BOOL) tabBarController:(UITabBarController*)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController*)viewController {
    BOOL didSelectContactTabButton = <determine if user selected "Contact" tab button> ;
    if ( didSelectContactTabButton ) {
        <create and present your MFMailComposeViewController> ;
        return NO ;
    }
    return YES ;
}
```